# jquery for the functionality of tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

i have 3 tabs place on my website

```
tab 1| tab 2 | tab 3
```

i am using jquery for the functionality of these tabs, however it is not working, the page shows only tab 1 details when i click on any other tab it doesn't get loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

<div class="tabs" ">
        <ul>
            <li data-tab="tab 1" class="active" ga-action="tab 1 Tab" ga-label="">tab 1</li>
            <li data-tab="tab 2" class="" ga-action="tab 2 Tab" ga-label="">tab 2</li>
            <li data-tab='tab 3' class=''>tab 3</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tab 1" class="tab active">
        <p> Written Material one </p>                               

        </div>

        <div id="tab 2" class="tab">
        <p> Written Material two </p>   
        </div>

        <div id="tab 3" class="tab">
        <p> Written Material three </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how can i make the tabs work

Comment: all you got to do is assign the class "tab active" on click to the clicked tab, and assign the class "tab" to other ones

Comment: @Brij Raj Singh i tried but it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the code you've posted:

- There's an orphaned double quote `"` in the top-level `div`. That's invalid HTML
- Your `<li>`s don't include any buttons/links. The `tabs` widget expects to have an `<a>` element within the `li`, with which to take the user to the corresponding tab
- Your content `div`'s `id` attributes contain spaces. That's invalid HTML.

To fix these change:

```
<div class="tabs">
...
<li data-tab="tab-1" class="active" ga-action="tab 1 Tab" ga-label="">
     <a href="#tab-1">tab 1</a>
</li>
...
<div id="tab-1" class="tab active">
...
```

Here's a working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9uvmktb8/

That's all the apparent problems, if it's still not working I'd look for the problem in omitted code. Let me know if this isn't the functionality wanted (as the question is a little unclear)

Comment: Few suggestions- The *orphaned* double quote isn't a blocker issue, So it can be the last point, or somewhere at the bottom of the post... Also it'd be nice if you make use of the inbuilt stack snippets rather than jsfiddle so that *I* don't have to open a new tab to see it working (*Yea me too use jsfiddle for playing with the issue especially because the libraries are readily available, but I don't save it there, when I post in SO I copy the code into a snippet*) Like I said, It's just a suggestion... :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently your are not telling your `li` elements where to go when clicked.
You can try the below code

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li class=''><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab active">
    <p> Written Material one </p>                               

    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab">
    <p> Written Material two </p>   
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3" class="tab">
    <p> Written Material three </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, with the help of `a` link we can tell that on click which tab to display.

Comment: it is changing the url of the page, but isn't displaying the data of the tab clicked, and another problem that has crept in is that when i click on tab 1 the page goes down and i have to scroll at the top of the page to see the data

Comment: I think you need to remove the classes you are using. You can see the details here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/